# In R optim will not return the maximum of a function and uniroot returns the wrong value

Tags: r

The function is:

```
f1 = function(x) {
  -1.3 * (x-0.1)^2+0.5 * (x-0.1)^5
}
```

I am trying to find the maximum in the interval [-1, 1].
The optimize functions returns the right value:

```
optimize(f1, interval = c(-1, 1), maximum = T)
```

This gives the result (which is correct):

```
$maximum
[1] 0.09999769

$objective
[1] -6.942984e-12
```

I am being asked (this question is for homework) to use optim and uniroot however. Tryng to use optim:

```
optim(par = c(-1, 1), fn = f1)
```

results in this error message (and this happens no matter what i do):

```
Error in optim(par = c(-1, 1), fn = f1) : 
  objective function in optim evaluates to length 2 not 1
```

While uniroot gives an answer that is clearly wrong:

```
uniroot(f1, lower = -1, upper = 1, f.lower = -1,  f.upper =1)
```

The result (clearly wrong):

```
$root
[1] 0.9998795

$f.root
[1] -0.7576706
```

So what is the issue here?

Comment: For the `optim` call there should only be one parameter but you have passed two. I think you will also need to negate the function. Also `method="L-BFGS-B"` allows box constraints, e.g. `optim(par=0, f1, control=list(fnscale=-1), method="L-BFGS-B", lower=-1, upper=1)`

Comment: That did work in making optim working correctly. Thanks. I'm still confused about why uniroot isn't working though.

Comment: `uniroot` is usually used to solve zeros, rather than finding maximum.

Comment: Well, i'm being asked in the problem set i'm trying to solve to use it to find a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
> optim(0, f1, lower = -1, upper = 1, method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(fnscale = -1))
$par
[1] 0.1

$value
[1] -4.806839e-26

$counts
function gradient
       5        5

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```